# Problem with application.properties (No such file or directory) when start jar application

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

I have my jar app with the name `myApp.jar`, and I have custom `application.properties` in the same folder in Linux. `/etc/myApp`

When I start `java -jar /etc/myApp/myApp.jar` in the folder `/etc/myApp` everything work well. But I have a problem when I want to start this command out of this folder(In my bash script).

I have an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   application.properties (No such file or directory)

I turned with:

```
java -jar /etc/myApp/myApp.jar -Dspring.config.location=file:/etc/myApp/application.properties
```

and

```
java -jar /etc/myApp/myApp.jar --spring.config.location=/etc/myApp/application.properties
```

And I have the same error.

This is  part where I using the application.properties

```
 Properties myProperty = new Properties();
 myProperty.load(new FileInputStream("application.properties"));
 MailBuilder mail = new MailBuilder(myProperty);
```

Comment: Are you sure file is present at `/etc/myApp/application.properties`?

Comment: Yes. And when I am in the `/etc/myApp/` I can run this command  `java -jar /etc/mayApp/mayApp.jar` but when I am on the `/etc` I have the exception.

Comment: Maybe the problem is permissions: This is my permissions `-rwxrwxrwx`

Comment: Could you provide a method of reading those .properties in code? Looks more like path problem.

Comment: I edited the post with sniped of code where I using `application.properties`.